# Thief - Probability

Tags: probability

I can not solve this problem, could you help me? The event was not very clear.

A thief who is planning to steal a safe between 9 and 10 pm estimates that it will take 5 minutes to open that safe, steal its contents and escape. He also knows that between 9 and 10 o'clock a guard will appear once to inspect the safe for 1 minute. Patrol is only started from 9 pm when conditions for safe theft are possible. The thief will only be arrested if he arrives in the room and the guard is there, or the guard appears when he is in the process of opening the safe. What is the probability of theft being successful in the following situations:

a) The thief enters the room in a time between 9:00 and 9:55 determined by a random process that guarantees uniform probabilities for any time in that period

b) The same situation of item (a) but with the complication that 2 guards will survey the room at random times (and independently) between 9 and 10 at night.

Comment: What does the sentence "Patrol is only started from 9 pm when conditions for safe theft are possible." mean?

Comment: There are two cases.  The guard is there when the thief arrives, or the guard arrives while the thief is mid caper.

Comment: the patrol starts at the same time as the possibility of stealing: at 9 pm

Comment: Doug, I realized that, but I could not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the times of thief and guard entering the room, respectively. Then, the feasible region for the guard catching the thief is:
$$0\le x\le 55; \ \ 0\le y\le 60;  \ \ x-1\le y\le x+5.$$
The probability of the thief being caught:
$$P=\frac{629.5}{55\cdot 60}=0.1908.$$
The probability of the thief being successful is :$1-0.1908=0.8092$.

Comment: I understood the region, but I did not understand the resolution of probability

Comment: @Muradin Think of the region as an area in the $x-y$ plane. The numerator is the area of the region subject to all three restrictions on $x,y$, while the denominator is just the first two restrictions.

Comment: It is $\frac{\text{Area of feasible}}{\text{Total area}}$.